# Bivariate Monte Carlo Integrator in R unable to run

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I have this code to calculate the probability of a bivariate normal distribution X~N(3, 16), Y~N(1,1) with correlation -(2/3) falling in the rectangle 0<X<4, and 0<y<1 with 100,000 samples in R.

```
for(i in 1:100000){
X[i] = runif(100000)
Y[i] = runif(100000)
Z[i] = runif(100000)
 if((3/(8*(pi)*sqrt(5)))*exp((-9/10)*(((X[i])^2/16)-((17/24)*(X[i]))+(X[i]*Y[i])/3)+((Y[i])^2)-(3*(Y[i]))+41/16) < Z[i])
count = count + 1}
```

count/100000 would be the probability of X, Y falling in the rectangle noted above.

When I run this, R returns an error saying

```
Error: object 'Z' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In X[i] <- runif(1e+05) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In Y[i] <- runif(1e+05) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

How would I fix this?

I tried running a similarly structured Monte Carlo integrator for the integral of x = 1, but this returned a similar error about replacement length.

Answer (score 0):

```
X <- rep(NA, 100000)
Y <- rep(NA, 100000)
Z <- rep(NA, 100000)


X[1:100000] <- runif(100000)
Y[1:100000] <- runif(100000)
Z[1:100000] <- runif(100000)
```

Define X, Y and Z, then allocate runif.
`runif` is vectorised, so no loop is required. This will get rid of your error and warnings.

```
count = 0
for (i in 1:100000){
  if((3/(8*(pi)*sqrt(5)))*exp((-9/10)*(((X[i])^2/16)-((17/24)*(X[i]))+(X[i]*Y[i])/3)+((Y[i])^2)-(3*(Y[i]))+41/16) < Z[i])
    count = count + 1}
```

This is assuming that you want to keep X, Y and Z for some other reason. You could use X, Y and Z as length 1 vectors, and replace them with new values on each cycle.

Your count calculation can also be vectorized:

```
counter[1:100000] <- rep(NA, 100000)
counter <- ((3/(8*(pi)*sqrt(5)))*exp((-9/10)*((X^2/16)-((17/24)*X)+(X*Y)/3)+(Y^2)-(3*Y)+41/16) < Z)

sum(counter)/length(counter)
```